# ReSharper: Possible NullReferenceException with Enumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, nullreferenceexception, ienumerator

ReSharper notifies me about a possible `System.NullReferenceException` for the following code:

```
 IEnumerator<IEdgeData> edgeEnumerator = edgeData.GetEnumerator();
 while (edgeEnumerator.MoveNext())
 {
    ConvId fromConvId = edgeEnumerator.Current.From;
    ...
 }
```

Specifically, it underlines:

```
edgeEnumerator.Current
```

I cannot figure out under which circumstances the exception could occur. My understanding is that the `while`-loops inner statements will only be executed if `MoveNext()` can set the enumerator on the next element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next element could actually be null. For example, the following code:

```
new List<SampleClass> { null, null, null }
```

will still give you an enumerator for each element, but the element itself is null.

Comment: The strange thing is that it doesn't underline anything if we use `foreach` instead.